# ScheduleAtFixedRate is not giving output using Future java 8

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, scheduled-tasks, java.util.concurrent

In the following code `scheduleAtFixedRate` runs endlessly.

So the question is:

**Why java provides the infinite thread execution scenarios**?

```java
Runnable task1 = () -> System.out.println("Hello Zoo");
Future<?> result = service1.scheduleAtFixedRate(task1, 8, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println(result.get());
System.out.println(result.isDone());
```

The program never prints the output of **`result.get()`** which should be null or **`System.out.println(result.isDone());`** which should be **0**.

So my point after calling **`scheduleAtFixedRate`** the code should be unreachable.

Comment: What does “after consuming scheduleAtFixedRate” mean? There nothing consumed in your code.

Comment: @Holger updated

Comment: Which code should be unreachable? And why?

Comment: @Holger After 3 and 4th line should not be reachable cause line 2 runs infinite time. As i got my answer please see my answer. Im closing the question. Thanks

Comment: The code *is* reachable. When you invoke `get()` on the `Future`, it will wait for a very long time, still, the thread could get interrupted or someone could cancel the `Future`, hence, the code is still not blocked forever, it’s only you who decides to never interrupt the thread and never cancel the future, but how could Java predict that you are not going to do that?

Comment: @Holger acquiesce your point same through like while(true) or for(;;).

Comment: This has nothing to do with `while(true)` or `for(;;)`. Infinite loops can not get interrupted or canceled and when you write an infinite loop, the compiler will flag code after the loop as unreachable. In contrast, the code in your question *is* reachable. It’s just waiting a long time due to the way you use it.

Comment: @Holger Thanks clear now

Answer (score 6):

[scheduleAtFixedRate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) returns a `Future` described thus:

> ... the task will only terminate via cancellation or termination of the executor.

So calling its `get` method will just wait forever because:

[Future.get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get())

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

So you are going to wait forever for the `Future.get()` method to return.

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
Future.get()
```

blocks until the process completes so your code sample will never execute the last two lines.  If you remove the second last line you should see **false** in the output.

Answer (score -2):

The answer which i got from internet and oracle doc is that :-

First :- you can create a program which runs infinate times like **`while(true)`** code.But java doesn't shows warning that break condition should be their.

Second :- Suppose you want to create a `system or daemon` thread then the method is used.

Third :- Yes if you want to terminate after certain time use another method :-

`Oracle should provide a method like which automatically terminate after given time elapsed.`

Comment: If you want `get()` to return after an elapsed time, just use [`get` with a timeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-). It’s not worth any discussion that there will be no timeout if you don’t specify a timeout.